# Delete row from many-to-many table (VB.Net, .edmx)

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many

I have Users and Regions. A User can be assigned to any number of Regions.

To implement this I have a table of Users, a table of Regions, and a third table UserRegion which is just UserID, RegionID (both columns form the primary key and they have foreign key relationships to the User and Region tables).

Entity Framework does not import the UserRegion table into my data model, instead it creates a property of each User object which is a list of Regions, and another on each Region object which is a list of Users. This is very useful except that I can't figure out how to un-associate a User from a Region.

The below code

```
Dim db as New DatabaseContext
Dim user = db.Users.Where(stuff).First()
user.Regions.Clear()
db.SaveChanges()
```

produces this error:

```
The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.
```

How can get rid of the relationship rows I don't want anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out.

The relationship needs to be removed from both sides. So the code should be:

```
user.Regions.Clear()
For Each r in db.Regions
    r.Users.Remove(user)
Next
db.SaveChanges()
```

Now I have a zillion for loops peppering this function but oh well. Hopefully this helps someone.